# Getting System.NullReference on File.Create

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I'm getting a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error when I try to create a file in a vb.net script task.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim sTestFileName As String = sPath & "testfile.txt"
Dts.Log("Testing file: " & sTestFileName, 0, emptyBytes)

If Not File.Exists(sTestFileName) Then
   Dts.Log("About to create file: " & sTestFileName, 0, emptyBytes)
   File.Create(sTestFileName)
   Dts.Log("Created file: " & sTestFileName, 0, emptyBytes)
Else
   Dts.Log("file: " & sTestFileName & " already exists!", 0, emptyBytes)
End If
```

If I use a different file path there aren't any errors.  The path in the log file looks fine.  Would a folder permission cause this error?

Comment: Use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to build paths, for example: `Dim sTestFileName As String = Path.Combine(sPath, "testfile.txt")`

Comment: And what is the path that raises the error?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is thrown by File.Create() ? The documentation doesn't list NullReferenceException as a possibility. Or   even are you sure it's an NRE you're getting ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Same error.

Comment: It writes to the log saying about to create the file \\filepath\testfile.txt.  Then it throws the error which would be on the File Create step.  If I use a different mapped path it doesn't have any issues.  There may be some read/write security on the directory as my windows account doesn't have access to the path but our service account does.  This process was running under the service account.

Comment: Here is the log:
User:ScriptTaskLogEntry,SERVER,USER,Set Processing Dates,1/13/2014 9:00:23 AM,About to try creating file: \\filepath\outputFolder\testfile.txt
OnError,SERVER,USER,Set Processing Dates,1/13/2014 9:00:23 AM,1,0x,System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ST_c169c0b488e924c6ed9b7b01c1d.vbproj.ScriptMain.SetOutputPath()
   at ST_c169c0b488e924c6ed9b7b01c1d.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: There is an account that the SSIS package is executing under. In Visual Studio, that is most likely your account. On the server, that will be dependent on how the package was launched but typically this is via SQL Agent job. The default for an Agent Job will be the account that runs the SQL Agent Service. Does *that* account have access to the network share? If it has access to the share, can it create a file. The job step *might* have a stored Credential from which it executes. Does *that* account have said rights?

Comment: Our proxy service account has access.  I can use the credentials from that account to map a network drive and see the data.  I'm sure there's some permission issue somewhere but a different team handles that.